# Python code to retry function

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to write a python function which retries a given function until given time or function returns True with given delay.

I have written the following function, but was thinking if there is a better way to do it?

**Example function I want to retry for**

```
def is_user_exist(username):

    try:
        pwd.getpwnam(username)
        log.info("User %s exist" % username)
        return True
    except KeyError:
        log.exception("User %s does not exist." % username)
        return False
```

**My retry function**

```
def retry(func, *func_args, **kwargs):
    retry_count = kwargs.get("retry_count", 5)
    delay = kwargs.get("delay", 5)
    while retry_count > 1:
        if func(*func_args):
            return
        log.debug("waiting for %s seconds before retyring again")
        sleep(delay)
        retry_count = retry_count - 1

    return func(*func_args)
```

Comment: Have a look at context managers. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740887/how-can-a-python-context-manager-try-to-execute-code

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek unless I misread that post, it doesn't seem possible to do with context managers

Comment: In my experience, retry functions are a code smell to begin with.

Comment: @jpmc26 why is that? There are plenty of situations where retrying automatically is valid (networking being the most obvious example)

Comment: @Dannnno It's *usually* an indication you're doing asynch wrong, like calling sleep is. The OP's specific example is local: if the user isn't already there, why will it be there in the near future? In the best case, they've got some process running asynchronously that might create it. But the more reliable way to do this is to wait for an entry in a queue *after* the user is created. If you're talking about something low level like implementing TCP, you have a point. But most code today is written at a higher level, and failure at these levels usually indicates a retry isn't going to work.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's definitely a good point. That being said, there are certainly cases where implementing something like this might not be the best solution, or the cleanest one, it may be the most pragmatic one to resolve an immediate issue. For that reason alone I think it has a valid place in a programmer's toolkit, as long as the tools right next to it are asynch and refactoring.

Comment: To give an example, a company I worked for had a network connection that was basically [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/908/). We had a lot of legacy code that relied on nobody tripping, and not built in a way to easily support being asynchronous. We implemented a similar method in the meantime, and by the time I left the company they had at least begun to restructure the code to handle such an outage more gracefully.

Comment: Very typically if you're doing retry you should probably use exponential/Fibonacci sleep times, for several reasons.

Comment: @WayneWerner really nice suggestion, I totally agree

Answer (score 25):

I like all of [Ev. Kounis'](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/188540/47529) answer, so I'll add some higher level details.

#### Let it be truth-y

Right now you aren't strictly requiring `func` to return `True` or `False`, just something truth-y or false-y. This is fine, and Pythonic. I think you would benefit from pointing that out in a docstring (which you should also write). Additionally, it may be worthwhile to return the actual value of `func(*func_args)` instead of `True` or `False`; this way you can actually get a value from the function if you wanted to take advantage of the truth-yness of the value.

#### Better `kwargs` support

You also don't allow any keyword arguments to be passed to the function - the function might support them, so you should to. I would promote the two keyword arguments you pull out of `kwargs` to explicit keyword arguments, with appropriate defaults (5 in your case).

#### Exceptions

It's weird to me that this function does have any concept of retrying after exceptions. I wouldn't want you to do something like this, for what I hope are obvious reasons

```
for _ in range(retry_count):
    try:
        if func(*func_args):
            return True
    except:
        pass
    log.debug("wating for %s seconds before retrying again")
    sleep delay)
```

However, in many cases I suspect you would know what exceptions you might expect (for example, a network timeout or connectivity blip) and that you might want to be handled by the retrying framework. To this end, I think something like this could be nice:

```
def retry(func, *args, retry_count=5, delay=5, allowed_exceptions=(), **kwargs):
    for _ in range(retry_count):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if result: return result
        except allowed_exceptions as e:
            pass
```

This obviously isn't a complete implementation; I left out some of the other pieces you have, and it behaves oddly if it fails on the last iteration, but it should be enough to start.

#### Fancy stuff

I think we could also get more value from this if it was a decorator. Then consumers of a function don't even need to know if they want it to retry or not; they just call their function and see that it works, and whether or not it was retried becomes irrelevant. Don't forget to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to preserve metadata.

```
import functools

def retry(retry_count=5, delay=5, allowed_exceptions=()):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(retry_count):
                # everything in here would be the same

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Then you can enable retrying for everyone, like so:

```
@retry(retry_count=5, delay=5)
def is_user_exist(username):
    try:
        pwd.getpwnam(username)
        log.info("User %s exist" % username)
        return True
    except KeyError:
        log.exception("User %s does not exist." % username)
        return False
```

#### Really fancy stuff

Why block when you're waiting? You could be doing so much more (this is for Python 3.5 and above) using [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep).  There isn't built-in support for this before that, but I know there are asynchronous frameworks that should be able to accomplish the same task.

By `await`ing an asynchronous function that just runs for `n` seconds, you achieve the same goal but allow other asynchronous functions to do work while you're just waiting. Note that depending on the event loop you might end up waiting for slightly more or less time.

I also cleaned up the issues I mentioned about handling exceptions; it now always returns the result of the function if it has one, and it'll re-raise the exception without losing any traceback if there was one. That also uses a Python 3 only feature; I've left a comment for how to do it in Python 2.

Note, I'm not as familiar with asyncio as I never got to do any serious dev there, so I might not have this piece of code exactly correct; the theory should be sound though.

```
import functools
import asyncio    

def retry(retry_count=5, delay=5, allowed_exceptions=()):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = None
            last_exception = None
            for _ in range(retry_count):
                try:
                    result = func(*func_args, **kwargs)
                    if result: return result
                except allowed_exceptions as e:
                    last_exception = e
                log.debug("Waiting for %s seconds before retrying again")
                await asyncio.sleep(delay)

            if last_exception is not None:
                raise type(last_exception) from last_exception
                # Python 2
                # import sys
                # raise type(last_exception), type(last_exception)(last_exception), sys.exc_info()[2]

            return result

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: Awesome post! What if I want to get a value through the retries? 
For example If I have a `last_page` to check for every iteration inside the function. And when I retry I don't want to do it all over again. But starting from that last_page. Is it possible?

Comment: @salvob no clue! If you get it to work feel free to post your code for review :)

Answer (score 15):

The only thing I noticed is that `retry` has a potentially **inconsistent** behavior.

Let me explain:

```
def retry(func, *func_args, **kwargs):
    retry_count = kwargs.get("retry_count", 5)
    delay = kwargs.get("delay", 5)
    while retry_count > 1:
        if func(*func_args):
            return
        log.debug("waiting for %s seconds before retyring again")
        sleep(delay)
        retry_count = retry_count - 1

    return func(*func_args)
```

> If `func` is successful while checking it **inside** the `while`,
>   `None` will be returned. On the other hand, if it is successful
>   **outside** the `while`, it will return whatever `func` returns (in your example `True`). You do not want to have that..

So I would propose a slight re-coding:

```
def retry(func, *func_args, **kwargs):
    retry_count = kwargs.get("retry_count", 5)
    delay = kwargs.get("delay", 5)
    for _ in range(retry_count):  # all tries happen in the loop
        if func(*func_args):
            return True           # if we succeed we return True
        log.debug("waiting for %s seconds before retyring again")
        sleep(delay) 
    return False                  # if we did not, we return False
```

---

You can get a bit fancier if you want to by subsituting the above `for` loop with this:

```
for _ in range(retry_count):
    res = func(*func_args) or log.debug("waiting for %s seconds before retyring again")
    if res is None:
        sleep(delay)
    else:
        return True
```

*Note that I am assuiming here that `log.debug` returns `None` but it does not really matter as long as it does not return `True`.*

Comment: Strictly speaking, it might not return `True` outside of the loop; it'll return whatever `func` does, which is probably something that can look truth-y or false-y.

Comment: @Dannnno Correct, I am just referring to OP's example `func`.

Comment: You don't pass `kwargs` to `func`, do you?

Answer (score 4):

## Theory

Your `retry` function is very similar to the structure of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Keeping only the essential, you could write `retry` as :

```
any(func(*func_args) for _ in range(count))
```

## Code

If you want `kwargs`, `log` and `sleep`, you can write:

```
def retry(func, *func_args, **kwargs):
    count = kwargs.pop("count", 5)
    delay = kwargs.pop("delay", 5)
    return any(func(*func_args, **kwargs)
               or log.debug("waiting for %s seconds before retyring again" % delay)
               or time.sleep(delay)
               for _ in range(count))
```

## Notes

- `log.debug` and `time.sleep` are both falsy, so `func or log or time` is truthy if and only if `func` is truthy.
- [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) is needed to extract `count` and `delay` from `kwargs`. They would get passed to `func` otherwise.

## Complete code

```
import time
import pwd
import logging as log

def is_user(username):
    try:
        pwd.getpwnam(username)
        log.info("User %s exist" % username)
        return True
    except KeyError:
        log.error("User %s does not exist." % username)
        return False

def retry(func, *func_args, **kwargs):
    count = kwargs.pop("count", 5)
    delay = kwargs.pop("delay", 5)
    return any(func(*func_args, **kwargs)
               or log.debug("waiting for %s seconds before retyring again" % delay)
               or time.sleep(delay)
               for _ in range(count))

retry(is_user, 'username', count=10, delay=0.5)
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of using `any` here; if you have a very limited set of functionality you want then it works fine and is very simple, but understanding why you're doing it that way is somewhat unintuitive. I also think that `or`ing together everything is somewhat ugly - that should be a separate function imo.

Comment: @Dannnno: Thanks for the comment. To each his own, I guess. OP's is basically interested in knowing if `func`will work at least once in `count` times, and that's pretty much what `any` is for. All the rest is optional decoration IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some problems with your current setup:

1. The function being retried can't take keyword arguments. This can be fixed pretty easily for the most part, but allowing the function to take arguments like `delay` will be more complicated.
2. To use retries, you have to call `retry(is_user_exist, username, ...)`. This makes it harder to avoid repetition.
3. You may end up with the same traceback appearing in the logs 5 times in a row.
4. `retry` requires that the function returns things in a certain way. This will be annoying for some functions when you have to add extra lines, and terrible for other functions where a falsy return value is valid.

I suggest a decorator such as the one below. I wrote this decorator a while ago and have happily used it in several places. The idea is similar to Dannnno's answer, but I only retry after exceptions and don't pay attention to return values.

```
def retry(num_attempts=3, exception_class=Exception, log=None, sleeptime=1):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(num_attempts):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except exception_class as e:
                    if i == num_attempts - 1:
                        raise
                    else:
                        if log:
                            log.error('Failed with error %r, trying again', e)
                        sleep(sleeptime)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Here is some usage in real code:

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

@retry(5, ConnectionError, log)
def request(self, method, url='', **kwargs):
    ...
```

Here's another example where I only retry at the call site, rather than changing the definition of the function:

```
retry(5, Exception, log)(ftp.get)(path, destination)
```

Your case is a bit unusual because an exception is involved but you ultimately don't want to raise it. You could perhaps rewrite your code as follows:

```
if is_user_exist(username):
    process_existing_user()
else:
    process_nonexistent_user()
```

becomes:

```
try:
    retry(5, KeyError, log)(pwd.getpwnam)(username)
except KeyError:
    process_nonexistent_user()
else:
    process_existing_user()
```

If you have other functions which you want to retry when a condition is false that don't involve exceptions, you could explicitly raise an exception:

```
class StuffNotFound:
    pass

@retry(exception_class=StuffNotFound)
def process_stuff():
    stuff = get_stuff():
    if not stuff:
        raise StuffNotFound()
    process(stuff)
```

Ultimately the problem with this question is that we're talking about how to write a very generic and widely applicable function, but we only have one use case to apply it to. If you have other examples of code you want to retry, this discussion can be more informed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one mentioned [tenacity](https://github.com/jd/tenacity) library.

It does exactly what you want + there is an already builtin implementation for asyncio. You can also use parameters(waiting then retrying, waiting x number of time, etc.) that are quite permissive.

Comment: Probably because it's not stdlib and including a module just for something you can easily code yourself like this is to high a price for that.

Answer (score -2):

You can replace your while loops and `retry_count` countdown with a simple for loop via [range()](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

```
def retry(func, *func_args, **kwargs):
    retry_count = kwargs.get("retry_count", 5)
    delay = kwargs.get("delay", 5)
    for _ in range(retry_count):
        if func(*func_args):
            return
        log.debug("waiting for %s seconds before retyring again")
        sleep(delay)

    return func(*func_args)
```

Comment: The point your making was already made in [another, earlier answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/188540/12390). I suggest to either edit this answer so that it adds new value, or else delete it.

Comment: @janos I saw that after posting it but I cannot figure out how to delete this post on the mobile app. I will when I get on the desktop site